# Excel Formula needed to lookup value in 1 spreadsheet & transfer it to another spreadsheet with the matching value

Tags: excel-2010

Every week I receive an excel file with approx 2,000 lines in it.  I need to be able to transfer the commission received for each unique stock item into my master file (separate spreadsheet)so that it shows against the same unique stock item.  I have tried using macros (at the moment I manually go through copy & paste to look up in the master file).  I have also tried IF function & VLOOKUP but can't seem to get it to paste the correct commission value.

This is an example of the file I receive:

```
Stock Number    Customer    Commission Value(Ex VAT)
8944125460285514045 MISS ASHLEY CONNELLY    9.16
8944125460285247596 MR ROLAND COOPER    9.15
8944125460233434510 MISS SHERYL SEELEY  10.25
8944125460286262784 MISS CLAIRE HARPER  10.23
8944125460286264392 MS JILL BROWN           10.23
8944125460285752322 MISS HAYLEY NICHOL  10.23
8944125460183834545 MR RICHARD OMAHONY  9.91
8944125460233404356 MISS ALICIA MORAN   9.90
8944125460326568455 MRS CHANTELLE BILLY 9.89
8944125460286263303 MRS VANESSA SMITH   9.89
8944125460285247893 MISS VENISHA MILLER 9.87
8944125460326089940 MR CRAIG HAINES         9.86
8944125460285658222 MR JAY DEE          9.84
```

This is a simplified version of my master file:

```
Stock Number            Customer Name           Comms Rec'd
8944125460286264392 JILL BROWN  
8944125460285247596 ROLAND COOPER   
8944125460233434510 SHERYL SEELY    
8944125460285658222 JAY DEE 
8944125460286262784 CLAIRE HARPER   
8944125460285514045 ASHLEY CONNELLY
```

I need a formula that will transfer the commission value from the received file to the comms rec'd column of the releveant stock number.

Answer (score 0):

SUMIF is what you need for this.

```
=SUMIF(RecievedFile!A:A,Master!A2,RecievedFile!C:C)
```

alter the references accordingly.

The function will search along the Stock Number column (`RecievedFile!A:A`) for the appropriate stock number (`Master!A2`) and sum up the values in the corresponding Commission column (`RecievedFile!C:C`)

---

To find the **first** Stock Number that matches, a VLOOKUP function will do that

```
=VLOOKUP(Master!A2,RecievedFile!A:C,3,FALSE)
```

This will look in the received file for the code from the master sheet in the first column, and return the value from the **3**rd column. (False means the list doesn't need to be sorted, and will only return an exact match). Note that this will only return the first tiem found, so if multiple items are in the file, the others will not be found.

Comment: Hi, thank you but I can't seem to get this work. It seeems to be adding up a lot of values rather than returning the single commission value for the corresponding stock number.

Comment: This will sum up all stock numbers, without regard to the customer name. If you need to take the customer name into account, then it will be a different formula

Comment: Ah that's what it was doing. I need it to return the single commission value for the corresponding stock number into the master file.

Comment: Hi, thanks for that but I need it to find all matching stock numbers and return the corresponding commission value to column 3.  I have 2,000 records per week I need to do this to.

Comment: then the SUMIF is the correct one. That will match **ALL** the stock numbers, and add them up, and give you the total of all commission earned under that stock number